# Camel netty component example doesn't work, within Spring MVC

Tags: spring, apache-camel, netty

I've tried out a good looking example in this topic ( http://shengwangi.blogspot.hu/2015/01/camel-netty-hello-world-simple-example.html ), but it doesn't work for me.
 I would like to create an simple workable TCP adapter, which uses an own encoder and decoder. At first I check out above example ( it uses a simple String encoder and decoder ) this way :

```
CamelContext ccontext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        try {
            ccontext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("netty:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&keepAlive=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder").to("bean:sayHello");
                }
            });

            ccontext.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And there are two beans, according the above example:

```
<!-- ChannelBuffer/ByteBuf to String -->
       <bean id="stringDecoder" class="org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder"/>

       <!-- String to ChannelBuffer/ByteBuf -->
       <bean id="stringEncoder" class="org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder"/>
```

When I try to start my implementation, i always get the this exception :

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[netty:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&kee... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: netty://tcp://localhost:7000?allowDefaultCodec=false&decoder=%23stringDecoder&encoder=%23stringEncoder&keepAlive=true&sync=true due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: decoder as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler with value #stringDecoder
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:192)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:805)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1906)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1767)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1735)
    at com.springapp.mvc.MainService.<init>(MainService.java:70)
    at com.springapp.mvc.MainService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9acc1320.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1763)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Could anybody help me ? Is it my fault, or the above example can't works ? Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a spring based camel context, eg

```
CamelContext ccontext = new DefaultCamelContext();
```

should be

```
CamelContext ccontext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
```

and then you need to get hold of the spring `ApplicationContext` so Camel can integrate with Spring and lookup the beans when you define then with `<bean>`.

An alternative is to setup `<camelContext>` in the spring xml file which then does all that for you, and then you can still define routes in java code. See Camel docs at: http://camel.apache.org/spring.html

Comment: Hi Claus! It almost works. I have changed the contexts, thereafter I don't get any exceptions, the application run in a Tomcat7 container. When I try join to it via telnet, the port:7000 is open, but when i send some characters the netty component close the port, and my service bean (EchoService) doesn't get the characters. Do you have any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Maybe its easier to use textline=true as option, then you dont need custom codecs.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 4 years since this question was asked, but maybe still valid to share a solution.
I'm using Netty Camel with Spring boot application and I had to add these two beans to the spring context in order to get sprint encoder and decoder working.

```
@Bean(name = "stringDecoder") 
public StringEncoder getStringEncoder() {
    return new StringEncoder();
}

@Bean(name = "stringEncoder") 
public StringDecoder getStringDecoder() {
    return new StringDecoder();
}
```

With that everthing is working fine for me.